# REST API Authentication in PHP - How to generate a signature

Tags: php, api, rest, signature

First, I'm pretty new to APIs, so I'm struggling to keep my head above water here... but either way, I need to generate a HMAC-SHA signature in PHP. How would I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "welcome<br />";
echo "welcome<br />";
echo hash_hmac('sha256', 'This is only a test sentence of gibberish.', 'secret123');
echo "<br />";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this answers my question... I still haven't been able to get the authentication to work, but I believe this part is correct